Use a GNU/Linux distro on a MicroSD card
1
I installed the latest Ubuntu on a MicroSD card successfully, but my MSI GP68 doesn't see any SD card when looking for bootable devices. I guess that it cannot boot from such SD card.
I wonder if there are any workarounds. Example: use a partition on my SSDs just too boot the OS on the microSD card like this:

partition /boot on SSD (can an existing and used one be used without formatting?)
partition /boot/efi on SSD ("  ")
partition / on the MicroSD


Do you have a sdcard to USB adapter?  A lot of times the card slot won't boot it, it's not really it's purpose.  Every time I use sd(or micro)card in the adapter, it will see it.

As you seem to have discovered that will entirely depend on the BIOS/UEFI capabilities of your computer. Most consumer grade PCs can't boot directly of SD. But some high-end servers can, and so can e.g. Raspberry Pis.

I resolved in the end by using a /boot and a /boot/efi partitions on an internal drive since I could not use a USB adapter.
For those that already have a system, especially the same one, on the internal hard drive, be careful: you might lose access to that system if you use the same /boot/efi.
